Extract return types of all functions in an interface
Imagine I have multiple interfaces:
interface ClassA {
    createMessage(basicInfo: string): string;
    calculateStuff(a: number, b: number): number;
    constant: number;
    someAction(): void;
}
interface ClassB {
    createTwoMessages(basicInfo: string): {message1: string, message2: string};
    calculateDifferentThing(a: number, b: number): number
}

and so on.
How do I create a type which extracts return types of all the functions from the interfaces? It would be ideal if it would filter out stuff that is not a function or functions returning void. I need it to work like this:
type ExtractReturnTypes<T> = ???

type ReturnTypesOfClassA = ExtractReturnTypes<ClassA>
// = {createMessage: string, calculateStuff: number}
type ReturnTypesOfClassB = ExtractReturnTypes<ClassB>
// = {createTwoMessages: {message1: string, message2: string}, calculateDifferentThing: number}

Basically it is an extention of ReturnType generic type, but applied to an entire object instead of a single function, while also naming the return types using the original function names and filtering out things that do not return a value. But so far I was not able to create it. Does anyone have an idea how can I do this please?

I don't understand why you're not using ReturnType.

Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz thats exactly that! thank you very much! Just one problem I did not realize before though - some functions return void. Is there some way to filter them out from the type?

Do you want the property to be absent from the resulting type if the return type is void? (Please [edit] the question to add this and any other requirement, and make sure your example reflects this.)

alright, I made the requirements a little more exact and exhaustive

Does this approach meet your needs? Detecting a void return type isn't very straightforward, so please test against a set of use cases you care about before responding.  If it meets your needs let me know and I'll write up an answer. Otherwise please [edit] to show a use case that isn't handled properly.

that is really amazing :D I never thought of such approach for removing the void. Thanks. that is exactly what I need!

I even found a little improvement (or simplification) - using [R, void] extends [void, R] seems unnecessary, I did not find a case where R extends void does not work the same way

What do you want {foo(): undefined} to produce?

Yeah I also found a few weird edge cases where I am not very sure why would they even happen and if the result in that case is a good one for me or not with the current solution. {foo(): undefined} is one such case. Currently this foo is not in the resulting type, which is fine I think. Also whenever a function's return type contains other types, like void | number or undefined | number, it is in the result and that is exactly what I need (although seeing the void | number type on a variable is a little weird :D )

Okay so, how should I proceed? I can write up my suggestion and then if you have other use cases later you'll deal with them offline? Or do you need more time to collect edge cases and [edit] the question?

I think the current solution is good and works rather well, in case I need some adjustments I think I now understand it well enough to deal with it on my own. Thank you.

You want ExtractReturnTypes<T> to be a mapped type over the properties of T, with some of the property keys suppressed if they don't correspond to functions with non-void return types. You can use key remapping with as to map the undesirable property keys to never:
type ExtractReturnTypes<T> = { [K in keyof T as (
    T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? (
        [R, void] extends [void, R] ? never : K
    ) : never
)]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never
}

Note that in both the remapped key and the value type we have to compute the conditional type T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? ⋯ : ⋯ to detect and extract the return type of the property function. This is redundant because you can't "cross" the boundary between the remapped keys and the mapped values of a mapped type.  Anyway, that conditional type is similar to how the ReturnType<T> utility type is implemented.
For the key, we suppress the property key if the value is either not a function (the last never) or if it's a function that returns void. Detecting a void return is tricky because undefined is assignable to void (see Why is undefined assignable to void?) and presumably we don't want to suppress undefined (or at least that's not in the question).  The check [R, void] extends [void, R] checks for mutual assignability between R and void. So if R is exactly void it will be caught. Otherwise it probably won't be caught (e.g., if R is narrower than void, wider than void, or unrelated to void).

Let's test it out:
interface ClassA {
    createMessage(basicInfo: string): string;
    calculateStuff(a: number, b: number): number;
    constant: number;
    someAction(): void;

}   
type ReturnTypesOfClassA = ExtractReturnTypes<ClassA>
/* type ReturnTypesOfClassA = {
    createMessage: string;
    calculateStuff: number;
} */

interface ClassB {
    createTwoMessages(basicInfo: string): { message1: string, message2: string };
    calculateDifferentThing(a: number, b: number): number
}
type ReturnTypesOfClassB = ExtractReturnTypes<ClassB>
/* type ReturnTypesOfClassB = {
    createTwoMessages: {
        message1: string;
        message2: string;
    };
    calculateDifferentThing: number;
} */

Looks good. The output types match what you wanted.
Playground link to code
